# SBT code generation and fork

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to generate code in SBT build for Slick like in the [example](https://github.com/slick/slick-codegen-example/blob/master/project/Build.scala).
However if I have

```
fork:=true
```

setting in the project - build fails with:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/runtime/package$
```

I want to keep that option to prevent memory leaks in my unit tests. If I get it right - there is no scala-reflect.jar loaded in forked jvm. But I have no idea how to load it.

Comment: Are you doing `libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a wrong assumption that SBT always loads all scala libraries by default, what appears to be incorrect for forked run. If I add scala-reflect dependency explicitly like Seth suggested it works ok.